# Discord converting time provided by the user to emojis before the bot can parse it

Tags: node.js, time

I have a discord bot in nodejs that requires user to give a time to convert it into unix, time is obtained via slash command. It works well for the most part. But when a I provide it with a `xx:18:xx`, it converts the `:18:` part into an emoji which is from a server that I'm in which then gives an invalid result. I tried to put bacticks to the time the bot gets but it seems the time bot gets is already altered by discord.

Here's the relevant part of the code.

```
const timeString = options.getString("time");

 const formattedTimeString = `\`${timeString}\``; // Here I added backticks to try to escape the emoji conversion

  const timezone = options.getString("timezone");

 const date = options.getInteger("date");

  const month = options.getString("month");

const year = options.getInteger("year");

 const currentDate = new Date();
 
const currentYear = year || currentDate.getFullYear();

  const currentMonth = month || currentDate.getMonth();

const currentDateValue = date || currentDate.getDate();


  let timestamp;

  if (date && month) {
 timestamp = moment.tz(`${date} ${month} ${year} ${formattedTimeString}`,  "DD MM YYYY HH:mm:ss",  timezone      )
     .valueOf();

  } else {

    timestamp = moment.tz(`${currentYear}-${currentMonth}-${currentDateValue} ${formattedTimeString}`, // Use formattedTimeString   "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss", timezone)

     .valueOf();
  }
```

I've attached a pic of the console showingwhat time the bot actually gets.

I was expecting it to not be converted into emoji ID's.
Here's a console pic showing what time it actually gets.
[Console Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGJac.jpg)